# Validating an array of dropdown boxes?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, validation

could someone help me please and see where I am going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Enter Name");
  return false;
  }
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["car[]"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Select Car");
  return false;
  }
}
  function add(tbl1) {
    var tb = document.getElementById(tbl1);
    var rowCount = tb.rows.length;
    var row = tb.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = tb.rows[1].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newCell = row.insertCell(i);
        newCell.innerHTML = tb.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="post.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<br><br>
<p>2. Your previous cars</p>
<table id="cars" border="1">

<tr><td width = "150"><center>Car</center></td>

</tr><tr>

</td><td><select name="car[]">
<option value="" selected=“selected”>Select one please</option>
<option value=Ford> Ford </option>
<option value=Audi> Audi </option>
<option value=Volvo> Volvo </option>
<option value=Nissan> Nissan </option>
<option value=Car 5>Car 5 </option>
</select></td>

</tr></table><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="add('cars')"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have created an array of cars so if personA has more cars, they can click add and select another one. If they have 1 car and just enter name and 1 car, the form works but when I click Add row and select another car, it doesnt work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `document.forms["myForm"]["car[]"]` is an element when there is one select element named "car[]", but it is an array (of elements) when there are multipel select elements named "car[]". Your validation assumes that it is always an element, so it fails.

You can either test if `document.forms["myForm"]["car[]"]` is an array, which you will likely find awkward, or you can use `document.getElementsByName("car[]")`, which will always return an array of elements for you to iterate over.

The following `if` would evaluate to true if the array was empty or the first element didn't meet your conditions for validity.

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("car[]");
if (x.length == 0 || x[0].value == null || x[0].value == "") { /* do stuff */ }
```

This solution assumes that only the first must be valid (given the lack of "remove car" button, this seems most resonable; if that is not your intention, iterate over them and return false if any fails to meet the validity condition.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple input fields with the same `name` attribute. If you press the `Add Row` button, your combo box is duplicated, however it keeps the same name and therefore `document.forms["myForm"]["car[]"].value;` becomes undefined.

One way to fix this is:

Make `<select name="car[]">` to `<select name="car[1]">` and change the inner loop of your javascript to the following:

```
newCell.innerHTML 
     = tb.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace("car[1]", "car["+rowCount+"]");
```

However you need to iterate over each `car[x]` now, in order to make the validation complete.

Comment: I would like to correct this: Multiple input fields with the same `name` is valid (indeed necessary for radio buttons), it is the `id` that must be unique.